# Difficulties in understanding how project works with mongoDB aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 pipelines that I used, I expect that both of them will return the same number of result when using count/itcount().

the first pipeline that I know is the correct one is: **count is 1597**

```
var pipeline = [
{ $match: { 
    "writers" : { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } }, 
    "cast" : { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } },
    "directors" : { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } } 
    }
},
{ $project : {
    "writers" : {
        $map : { 
            input: "$writers",
            as: "writer",
            in: { 
                $arrayElemAt: [
                    { $split: [ "$$writer", " (" ] },
                    0
                ]}
        }
    },
    "cast" : 1,
    "directors" : 1 
    }
},
{ $project: 
    { "laborOfLove": { $gt: [ { $size: { $setIntersection: ["$writers", "$cast", "$directors"] } }, 0 ] } }
},
{ $match : { "laborOfLove" : true } }];
```

the second pipeline that I wrote and returns fewer documents: **count is 1293**

```
 var pipeline = [
{ $match: {
        "writers" : { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } }, 
        "cast" : { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } },
        "directors" : { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } } 
        }
    },
  {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        writers: {
          $map: {
            input: "$writers",
            as: "writer",
            in: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $split: [ "$$writer", " (" ]
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        directors: 1,
        cast: 1,
        "laborOfLove": { $gt: [ { $size: { $setIntersection: ["$writers", "$cast", "$directors"] } }, 0 ] } 
    }},
    { $match : { "laborOfLove" : true } }
]
```

why I am getting a different number of results?

I'm doing the mongoDB university aggregation framework course, this is the link to the data:

> mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/aggregations?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl -u m121 -p aggregations --norc

and after creating the pipeline we can run the query like this:

```
db.movies.aggregation(pipeline).itcount()
```

Comment: `count is 1597` - have you tried to remove the last line of project and see how much would you get?

Comment: Can you post any sample data? It's hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm doing the mongoDB university aggregation course. the data is in here :mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/aggregations?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl -u m121 -p aggregations --norc

Comment: without the last project & match the result is:40834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the situation, I need to put the laborOfLove in a new stage because in the logical order if it's in the same stage I'll go iterate over the writes in the wrong format and that's the reason I get a lower number.

Comment: In 2nd query, while evaluating laborOfLove field you can replace the "$writers" in $setIntersection with $map code.

Answer (score 0):

Official solution copied & pasted:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      cast: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } },
      directors: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } },
      writers: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      cast: 1,
      directors: 1,
      writers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$writers",
          as: "writer",
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $split: ["$$writer", " ("]
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      labor_of_love: {
        $gt: [
          { $size: { $setIntersection: ["$cast", "$directors", "$writers"] } },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { labor_of_love: true }
  },
  {
    $count: "labors of love"
  }
])
```

With our first $match stage, we filter out documents that are not an array or have an empty array for the fields we are interested in.

```
{
  $match: {
    cast: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } },
    directors: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } },
    writers: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } }
  }
},
```

Next is a $project stage, removing the _id field and retaining both the directors and cast fields. We replace the existing writers field with a new computed value, cleaning up the strings within writers

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      cast: 1,
      directors: 1,
      writers: {
          $map: {
            input: "$writers",
            as: "writer",
            in: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $split: ["$$writer", " ("]
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

We use another $project stage to computer a new field called labor_of_love that ensures the intersection of cast, writers, and our newly cleaned directors is greater than 0. This definitely means that at least one element in each array is identical! $gt will return true or false.

```
{
  $project: {
    labor_of_love: {
      $gt: [
        { $size: { $setIntersection: ["$cast", "$directors", "$writers"] } },
        0
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

Lastly, we follow with a $match stage, only allowing documents through where labor_of_love is true. In our example we use a $match stage, but itcount() works too.

```
{
  $match: { labor_of_love: true }
},
{
  $count: "labors of love"
}

// or

  {
    $match: { labor_of_love: true }
  }
]).itcount()
```

This produces 1596.